# How to apply all edits to two meshes, but mirrored along an axis?

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms, mirror

I am modelling an airplane. I need to e.g. rotate some faces of both wings (they are separate meshes that are exactly symmetrical along the X axis) around their local center. I tried to simply select faces of both wings and rotating them, but that way they both were rotated clockwise, whereas the faces of the left wing should be rotated counter-clockwise and the faces of the right wing should be rotated clockwise. I think of a functionality similar to the `Mirror` modifier, but live, and acting on an already existing vertices instead of creating new ones. Is this possible ? Of course it should also work for other transformations, and for vertex / edge/ face deletions (or creations)

Comment: if you don't want the Mirror modifier, there's a XYZ symmetry option on the top right, but it acts like the Mirror modifier. How what you ask is different from the Mirror modifier btw? Also, you can symmetrize your mesh whenever you want (Mesh > Symmetrize and check the Operator box on the bottom left of your 3D view), if you've lost the symmetry between left and right it's a way to get it back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Why don't use Mirror modifier?

Mirror has an option "Mirror object". You can set here a central part of your plane or add an empty:

[image]

[image]

#### 2. Linking object.

If you want to keep left a right wing separate, maybe it is a good option.

Copy one part of the ring with linking (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) then mirror it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Two objects will be separated, but geometry will be shared, and all changes will appear on both sides.

[image]

Note, that you can make links by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> -> **Object Data** also and remove links by **Object** ⇾ **Relationships** → **Make Single User** ⇾ **Object & Data**

#### 3 Symmetrize whole wing.

If you have lots of objects, and you want to mirror them all at once, it is your option. Make a new collection from one wing, when add an instance of it to the scene and mirror it:

[image]

Now not only geometry, but objects itself mirrored.

If in the future you will need to break apart this mirrored part, simply press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> - **make duplicates real**

Comment: Thank you - solutions 2 and 3 are just what I needed !